# filtering any columns of a database table client T-SQL select from case when then where

Tags: t-sql, syntax, sql-server-2014

I would like to be able filter through the columns of a datagrid but don't know how to fix the select statement this is as far as I could get

```
SELECT 
    ClientID, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, StreetName, 
    City, State, ZipCode, CellPhone 
FROM 
    dbo.Client 
CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'ClientID' THEN WHERE @ColumnName = @Filter END
CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'FirstName' THEN WHERE @ColumnName LIKE @Filter END 
CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'LastName' THEN WHERE @ColumnName LIKE @Filter END 
CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'BirthDate' THEN WHERE @ColumnName = @Filter END 
CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'StreetName' THEN WHERE @ColumnName LIKE @Filter END 

CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'City' THEN WHERE @ColumnName LIKE @Filter END 
CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'State' THEN WHERE @ColumnName LIKE @Filter END 
CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'ZipCode' THEN WHERE @ColumnName LIKE @Filter END  
CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'CellPhone' THEN WHERE @ColumnName LIKE @Filter END;
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: It's useless to use `LIKE` in the way that you are. Unless you're passing in some unexpected variable. You can use `LIKE '%'+@Filter+'%'`

Comment: @AndreyKaplun - Are you passing `%` in `@Filter` as BJones mentioned?

Comment: @BhavinGosai Yes I am

Comment: Have a look at [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this query:**

```
SELECT ClientID, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, StreetName, City, State, 
ZipCode, CellPhone 
FROM dbo.Client 
WHERE 
CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'ClientID' AND ClientID = @Filter THEN 1
WHEN @ColumnName = 'FirstName' AND FirstName LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' THEN 1
WHEN @ColumnName = 'LastName' AND LastName LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' THEN 1
WHEN @ColumnName = 'BirthDate' AND CASE WHEN ISDATE(@Filter) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @Filter, 101) ELSE NULL END = BirthDate THEN 1
WHEN @ColumnName = 'StreetName' AND StreetName LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' THEN 1

WHEN @ColumnName = 'City' AND City LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' THEN 1
WHEN @ColumnName = 'State' AND State LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' THEN 1
WHEN @ColumnName = 'ZipCode' AND ZipCode LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' THEN 1 
WHEN @ColumnName = 'CellPhone' AND CellPhone LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' THEN 1
WHEN @ColumnName = '' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END = 1
```

**Query Explanation:**

- When you pass any column name and filter which matches to any records and per column name, it will return those records.
- When column name matches and no record matches as per column name it fallback to last `ELSE` part so it won't return any records as expected.
- All the filters apart from `ClientID` and `BirthDate` has wild card syntax, which will help for partial match.
- In one special case when you don't mention any column name i.e. `@ColumnName = ''` then all rows will be returned as you didn't want to filter. You can easily change this additional behavior by removing this line `WHEN @ColumnName = '' THEN 1`

Comment: SqlException "Operand type clash: Date is incompatible with int "

Comment: @andrey-kaplun - What is value of your `@Filter`?

Comment: The values are 2 for `Filter` and ClientID for `ColumnName`

Comment: @andrey-kaplun - I have now updated query as per your inputs. Please give it a try now. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: SqlException "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Case'"

Comment: Try removing a line with BirthDate temporarily and check if it works. i.e. remove `WHEN @ColumnName = 'BirthDate' AND CASE WHEN ISDATE(@Filter) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @Filter, 101) ELSE NULL END = BirthDate THEN 1` and try.

Comment: It works I just needed to put a space between from and where :) thanks for your time and effort

Answer (score 0):

You should try to refer to the actual column in your where clause, as @ColumnName contains name, rather than referring to the column value. By "WHERE @ColumnName = @Filter", we compare the name of the column. By "WHERE ClientID = @Filter", we compare the value of the column. Maybe, you should do it this way:

```
SELECT ClientID, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, StreetName, City, State, 
ZipCode, CellPhone 
FROM dbo.Client 
CASE 
  WHEN @ColumnName = 'ClientID' THEN ClientID
  WHEN @ColumnName = 'FirstName' THEN FirstName
  WHEN @ColumnName = 'LastName' THEN LastName 
  WHEN @ColumnName = 'BirthDate' THEN BirthDate
  WHEN @ColumnName = 'StreetName' THEN StreetName
  WHEN @ColumnName = 'City' THEN City
  WHEN @ColumnName = 'State' THEN State
  WHEN @ColumnName = 'ZipCode' THEN ZipCode
  WHEN @ColumnName = 'CellPhone' THEN CellPhone
END
LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `or` in the `where` is cleaner here

```
SELECT ClientID, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, StreetName, City, State, 
       ZipCode, CellPhone 
FROM dbo.Client  
where (@ColumnName = 'ClientID'  and ClientID     = @Filter) 
   or (@ColumnName = 'FirstName' and FirstName LIKE @Filter)
   or (@ColumnName = 'LastName'  and LastName  LIKE @Filter) 
...;
```